# Can not include linked with CMake third-party library

Tags: c++, cmake, clion, apple-m1

I am trying to use an fmt library in my C++ project for formatting.
I have installed the package with anaconda.

Afterwards, in my CMake file I have found the fmt package and link:

```
set(fmt_DIR "/opt/anaconda3/lib/cmake/fmt/")
find_package(fmt REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(<my_target> fmt)
```

But even though these steps are done, I run into "**fatal error: 'fmt' file not found**", when trying to `#include <fmt>`

I am probably missing something obvious. Would appreciate any help.

Comment: Have you read [documentation](https://fmt.dev/latest/usage.html#usage-with-cmake)? It tells that after `find_package(fmt)` one should link with `fmt::fmt`: `target_link_libraries(<your-target> fmt::fmt)`. But you link with `fmt`...

Comment: Oops, I missed that. Thank you a lot. And sorry for such a trivial issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Tsyvarev mentioned in comment:

> ... after `find_package(fmt)` one should link with `fmt::fmt`: `target_link_libraries(<your-target> fmt::fmt)`.

So using `target_link_libraries(<your-target> fmt::fmt)` instead of `target_link_libraries(<your-target> fmt)` works perfectly.